# How can i integrate p5.js with nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, p5.js

i'm trying to integrate p5.js with nuxt.

```
  mounted () {
    const sketch = (s) => {
      s.setup = () => {
        s.createCanvas(500, 500)
      }
      s.draw = () => {
        s.background(33, 33, 33)
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const canvas = new P5(sketch, 'p5Canvas')
  },
```

i tried do it here, but i'm getting Window is not defined error.
i also tried to this this in Created instead of Mounted, but outcome was the same.

Comment: take a look to this blog post https://caballerocoll.com/blog/set-up-p5-in-nuxt/

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically import `p5` in your `mounted` function as follows:

```
  async mounted () {
    const { default: P5 } = await import('p5')

    const sketch = (s) => {
      s.setup = () => {
        s.createCanvas(500, 500)
      }
      s.draw = () => {
        s.background(33, 33, 33)
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const canvas = new P5(sketch, 'p5Canvas')
  },
```

Comment: mmmhh.... I get 'P5 is not defined' or 'p5 is not a Constructor'

Comment: there was a typo... `const P5 = await import('p5')`

Comment: I expected that typo. This results in the second error message 'P5 is not a Constructor'

Comment: you right, the `p5` module doesn't export the constructor by default... I just updated my answer with `const { default: P5 } = await import('p5')`

Comment: That works great! Thanks. Is there a difference to the `<client-side>` `if(process.client)` method described in your other comment? 
This seems much cleaner to me

Comment: it's complementary. You can use the `<client-side>` but only on the template, but you have to import "p5" on `<scripts>`, so the `if (process.client)` cannot handle the `import('p5')`.... Another way is to create a nuxt plugin on client side only to init a global `p5` lib : https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/#client-or-server-side-only . Or probably the best way, you can just use `vue-p5` inside a `<client-side>` element (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-p5) so without import `p5` manually.

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt `mounted` and `created` lifecycle methods are run on both client and server side. While it will work as expected on the former, it won't work on the latter, since there is no `window` object server side.

You can make this code run on client side only with:

```js
if (process.browser) {
  // Your code
}
```

Comment: ```   created () {
    if (process.browser) {
      const sketch = (s) => {
        s.setup = () => {
          s.createCanvas(500, 500)
        }
        s.draw = () => {
          s.background(33, 33, 33)
        }
      }
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      const canvas = new P5(sketch, 'p5Canvas')
    }
  }, ``` still the same error... and if im using process.client same error as well

Comment: So this is probably related to another part of code. This error is quite classic in Nuxt, it can happens when : - you don't include your plugin as "client" in nuxt config file. - you don't use if (process.browser) { ... } in server side code that need window object. - you are using a component that uses window without putting it inside <client-only> tag

Comment: so do you have some tutorial how to integrate nuxt with p5? i tried so many things now... i have my canvas in <client-only> tags already

Comment: when im only doing import P5 from 'p5' i'm getting Window is not defined as well